# Pass function's return value as a parameter to Other function in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a ExamResult table, 2 function and a query which I put below.

I want to pass return value of ufn_Totalmarks function as parameter to ufn_Averagemarks to get average marks of student but It gives error "Invalid column name 'Totalmarks'."

I can do this thing to pass function one as parameter to function 2 but in my real case I do not want to do this because its a complex functions and query execution is very slow.

This is just a demo example I have created to ask a question.

ExamResult Table Data as below Image:

[image]

Functions :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_Totalmarks] 
(
    @Marks1 int,
    @Marks2 int
)
RETURNS  int
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result int
    SELECT @Result =  @Marks1 + @Marks2
     return @Result

END
GO


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_Averagemarks] 
(
    @TotalMarks int

)
RETURNS  int
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result int
    SELECT @Result =  @TotalMarks/2
     return @Result

END
GO
```

Query :

```
Select [dbo].[ufn_Totalmarks](Marks1,Marks2) as Totalmarks, [dbo].[ufn_Averagemarks](Totalmarks) as AvgMarks,  * from ExamResult
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a [Common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) or a subquery.

**Common table expression**

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ID, StudentID, Marks1, Marks2, dbo.ufn_TotalMarks(Marks1, Marks2) AS TotalMarks
    FROM dbo.ExamResult
)
SELECT ID, StudentID, Marks1, Marks2, TotalMarks, dbo.ufn_Averagemarks(TotalMarks) AS AvgMarks
FROM CTE;
```

**Subquery**

```
SELECT ID, StudentID, Marks1, Marks2, TotalMarks, dbo.ufn_Averagemarks(TotalMarks) AS AvgMarks
FROM (
    SELECT ID, StudentID, Marks1, Marks2, dbo.ufn_TotalMarks(Marks1, Marks2) AS TotalMarks
    FROM dbo.ExamResult
) AS subquery;
```